# Check if the Messaging Active Configuration is configured through API

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

is there any way to check if a phone number's Messaging Active Configuration is configured or not, through the API?

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the IncomingPhoneNumbers resource to do so.

[IncomingPhoneNumber resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource)

See the code examples (Fetch/List)

For a Messaging Service (to see if a number is in a messaging service):

1. Read Service Example.
   This will list all the Messaging Services in the given Account SID
   Service Resource

https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/services/api

Example:

```
client.messaging.services
                .list({limit: 20})
                .then(services => services.forEach(s => console.log(s.sid)));
```

2. Fetch Service
   For each Messaging Service, you need to fetch the numbers it contains, You need to do this for each Messaging Service SID (#1 above)

PhoneNumber Resource

https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/services/api/phonenumber-resource

Example:

```
client.messaging.services('MGxxx')
      .phoneNumbers
      .list({limit: 20})
      .then(phoneNumbers => phoneNumbers.forEach(p => console.log(p.phoneNumber)));
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't show the Messaging Service: Default Conversations Service,

Comment: For the second number, it shows the configured Hooks, however, I was more interested in knowing that the first number is using the Messaging Service: Default Conversations Service. That information is not returned